# Accessing values send by serialize function in a json format

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following code in js:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.when(getDatas(this.id)).done(function(r_getDatas){
        $('#loader').toggleClass("show hide");
    });

    function getDatas(id) {
        return $.post("update.php", {
            updateType: id,
            data: $('#'+id).serialize()
        }, "json");
    }           
});
```

How to access the serialized values in PHP ?

I tried `print_r($_POST)` without success.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to put it inside the function in the first place, just invoke your `$.post`. and also, console browser/network tab is your friend

Comment: I agree with @Ghost, however, what is the output of 

`return $.post('update.php', $('#' + id).serialize());`

Comment: you keep making this far more complicated than needed. Since your last question with same code you added `$.when` which just isn't needed. get your code working with a very simple `$.post` and get rid of all the other crap. Inside the submit you can use `$(this).serialize()` for the data

Comment: @RhapX returning any `$.ajax ` method returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

use `serializeArray()` :

```
function getDatas(id) {
    return $.post("update.php", {
        updateType: id,
        data: $('#'+id).serializeArray()
    }, "json");
}
```

Try it once more